# List alphabetically in vertical columns , css?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a 9 columns list that are alphabetically organized in horizontal view, but I would like it to be sorted vertical. How do I do this, preferably using css? Tinkered with column-count but can't make it happen.. Site in question: http://www.skatevids.me/fullvideos

Css:

```
li.listing-item {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0 -10px 0 0;
width: 110px;
font-size: 11px;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you show an example of what you have now? html, css

Comment: Updated with the css. As far as html goes, I output my list with a short code for pages.

Comment: Is what you're saying that you have a list where each row has 9 columns? or do you have a list that consists out of 9 items that are listed in vertical columns?

Comment: I have a list that is sorted in 9 columns. You can see it here: www.skatevids.me

Comment: I don't see a 9 cols list there. I see a list of videos that have 4 columns. If you can't be more specific we cannot help you.